# Save to array to DB from best_in_place gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have this code

```
= best_in_place [@project, @cross_word], :wordarray, :type => :input
```

wordarray is saved as serialize. Now I want to read/write some data

```
= best_in_place [@project, @cross_word], :wordarray, :type => :input
```

This code is working, bug I have some errors, because typed data is not array(normal)

```
= best_in_place [@project, @cross_word], :wordarray[1], :type => :input
= best_in_place [@project, @cross_word], :wordarray[2], :type => :input
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't work. I don't know how read/write some data from/to array in DB. Anybody know how I can write/read data through best_in_place gem?
Thanks for help :)

Comment: well `:wordarray` is simply a symbol so `[]` will return `o` for `[1]` and `r` for `[2]` as it will call `String#[]`. Your question is slightly unclear as to the intended result please rephrase so we can understand your intentions.

Comment: I want to read/save element in array from db through best_in_place. Script in view will be create array.count textinputs and
read value to this input. Conclusion: How to read n element of array from db to (textinput) best_in_place gem ?

Comment: can you please explain a bit further do you just want `@project` in one input and `@cross_word` in another? What types of objects are these as I feel you should be able to filter out the values on the objects themselves.

Comment: I want only @cross_word.
`class CrossWord < ActiveRecord::Base
  include RankedModel
  ranks :row_order

  belongs_to :project

  validates_presence_of :title

  serialize :wordarray, Array ####
end`
How to read x element from wordarray into best_in_place ?